# Chrome Ignore PHP locally

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have web pages that are using PHP for various functions and as such the page extensions are .php

But for the moment I'm doing some routine work on HTML elements within those pages. The PHP portions do not affect the layout, but I am using Chrome primarily for preview of changes.

Chrome of course likes to display a PHP file in code view, while I could change the extension of the page to .htm or .html until the changes are done, I'm curious if anyone has found a Chrome config setting or a Chrome extension that allows for PHP parsing on a local file by Chrome to be ignored/disabled and treated simply as HTML.

Just trying to see if there is a simpler flag on/off function discovered somewhere as opposed to a bunch of file renaming.

Comment: Can you just set it up on localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Josh if your talking about setting up PHP locally, I could but have not interest in doing that on the local machine. If your talking about something else then elaborate as maybe i'm not following?

Comment: If you host a “website”/webpage on you local machine  (its only accessible by your computer), then go to 127.0.0.1 in Chrome, Chrome would treat it has a normal website and it should work. You would just need PHP to be installed on your computer | What type of computer do you have? On Mac PHP is preinstalled and it’s very easy to do what I suggest. Not sure about PC, but I reckon it’s not too difficult.